# Attach JQuery Mobile DatePicker / Calendar dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I attach a JQuery **Mobile** DatePicker dynamically to an input field ?

I tried using [ui-datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), but I think the plugin attaches Calendar to the input field that has the required markup. How do I dynamically attach a calendar using Javascript ? I tried the following

```
$("#datep").after( $( "<div />" ).datepicker({ 
    altField: "#datep"
}) );
```

but the Calendar does not hide after the date has been chosen.

I also explored [jQM-DateBox2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/), but couldn't figure out a way to attach calendar dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?  You are creating the input field on the fly, or...?

Comment: Yes, I want to create input field on the fly and make them calendars. Also, I have a use case where I want to convert an existing input field into a calendar programatically.

Comment: Also, I want to limit calendar dates. How do I provide the values min="2001-01-02" max="2001-01-25" programatically ? Passing it in the same JSON is not working for me {"mode": "calbox", 'min':"2013-01-02", 'max':"2013-01-25"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with DateBox, you could do something like:

```
$('<input data-role="datebox" ...etc.. >').appendTo(whatever).trigger('create');
```

OR, you could add the input field wherever you like, and then

```
$('#added_element').datebox({<optional options});
```

Comment: Also, I want to limit calendar dates. How do I provide the values min="2001-01-02" max="2001-01-25" programatically ? Passing it in the same JSON is not working for me {"mode": "calbox", 'min':"2013-01-02", 'max':"2013-01-25"}

Comment: no, it wouldn't yet - I'll work on adding those as real options instead of just min/max attributes.

Comment: update on the above comment - you can dynamically set the min/max HTML5 attributes - then do a .datebox('applyMinMax') to get it to re-read them (or add them before you hit the original .trigger('create') and it should have already noticed them.